# How to hide ckeditor when we click outside of the editor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, lostfocus

Here is my code:

```
<div id="showReplyDiv">
  <form id="test">
   <div>
       <textarea id="articleEditor" name="articleVO.articleC"></textarea>
           <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'articleEditor',{customConfig : '/Forum/ckeditor/replyCKEditor.js'}); 
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonArea">
        <input type="button" id="doReply" value="submit"/>
        <input type="button" id="cancel" value="cancel"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want it so that when the user clicks anywhere outside of this `ckEditor`, I can hide it.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? You need to ask a specific question, not ask for someone to solve your problems for you.

Comment: sorry, i am the beginner of jquery and ckeditor,about two days,and i had try some ways ,but it doesn't work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').click(function(event){

    if($(event.target).parents('#articleEditor').length <= 0)
         $('#articleEditor').hide();
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i alter it a litter and works for my application

Comment: hello,there has another question,when i want to insert a image,i click the botton on the toolbar,then select one image,but  the ckeditor disappeared

Answer (score 1):

The solution to a similar problem wasn't working for me due to clicks in dialog widgets. I ended up using

```
$('body').click(function(event){

    if($(event.target).parents('#articleEditor').length <= 0 && $(event.target).parents('.cke_dialog').length <= 0)
         $('#articleEditor').hide();
})
```